# How to define private zone id in Alicloud

Tags: cloud, terraform, alibaba-cloud

I am currently working on Alicloud and wanted to define DNS for GPDB resource using `alicloud_pvtz_zone_record` but getting error as below.

```
Error: [ERROR] terraform-provider-alicloud/alicloud/resource_alicloud_pvtz_zone_record.go:167: Resource alicloud_pvtz_zone_record AddZoneRecord Failed!!! [SDK alibaba-cloud-sdk-go ERROR]:
SDK.ServerError
ErrorCode: Record.Invalid.Value
Recommend: 
RequestId: A69A1D2A-19A8-48D9-A5AC-EF3BB85C9CFE
Message: Record value is invalid.

  on ../../main.tf line 32, in resource "alicloud_pvtz_zone_record" "pvtz_zone_records":
  32: resource "alicloud_pvtz_zone_record" "pvtz_zone_records" {
```

Below is my terraform code.

```
resource "alicloud_gpdb_instance" "gpdb_instance" {
  description          = "tf-gpdb-test"
  engine               = "gpdb"
  engine_version       = "4.3"
  instance_class       = var.gpdb_instance_class
  instance_group_count = var.gpdb_instance_group_count
  vswitch_id           = var.vswitch_id
  security_ip_list     = var.allowed_ips
}

resource "alicloud_pvtz_zone_record" "pvtz_zone_records" {
  zone_id         = var.dns_zone_id
  resource_record = "server.gpdb"
  type            = "CNAME"
  value           = alicloud_gpdb_instance.gpdb_instance.id
  ttl             = var.dns_ttl
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terraform [doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/alicloud/r/pvtz_zone_record.html), `alicloud_pvtz_zone_record` resource accepts value domain only.

In your example, `alicloud_pvtz_zone_record`'s value **accepts ID from  gpdb instance**. That's why Terraform produces **invalid value**.

Here's solution by adding `alicloud_gpdb_connection` resource [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/alicloud/r/gpdb_connection.html):

```
resource "alicloud_gpdb_connection" "gpdb_connection" {
  instance_id = alicloud_gpdb_instance.gpdb_instance.id
}

resource "alicloud_pvtz_zone_record" "pvtz_zone_records" {
  zone_id         = var.dns_zone_id
  resource_record = "server.gpdb.pgsoft.local"
  type            = "CNAME"
  value           = alicloud_gpdb_connection.gpdb_connection.connection_string
  ttl             = var.dns_ttl
}
```

`alicloud_gpdb_connection` resource outputs **connection_string which is value of domain** from particular gpdb instance.